# Confusion on Surjectivity and Continuity in a Topological Map.

Tags: general-topology

I've been going over the definitions of continuity and surjectivity with respect to topological maps, and wanted to ask a clarifying question.

Let $f : (X,\tau_X)\to (Y,\tau_Y)$ be a surjective mapping of two topological spaces. In general, does surjectivity imply that the mapping $f$ is continuous? I know that a mapping between two topological spaces is said to be continuous if for every $U\in\tau_Y$, $f^{-1}(U)\in\tau_X$. That is, the pre-image of an open set is open.  Since things (sets) in topologies are called *open*, does that mean that a topological surjective map would automatically be continuous?

Proof: Assume $f: (X,\tau_X)\to (Y,\tau_Y)$ is a surjective map between two topological spaces. Let $B \in \tau_Y$ be arbitrary.  Since $f$ is surjective, it follows that for every $B \in \tau_Y $, there exists some $A \in \tau_X$ such that $f(A) = B$. So, there exists some $f^{(-1)}(B)$
for every $B\in \tau_Y$.

I feel like generally this is not true, and I am assuming that the last line in my proof is where things can go wrong, but I can't seem to see it clearly, (I think its maybe the order of quantifiers $\forall\exists \neq \exists\forall$), so I would greatly appreciate an explicit counter example of a surjective non-continuous map of two topological spaces if possible. Thank you.

Comment: No, take $$f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R,\ x\mapsto \begin{cases} x & \text{if}\ x < 0 \\ -x +1 & \text{if}\ 0 \le x \le 1 \\ x & \text{if}\ 1 < x  \end{cases}$$

This map is surjective but not continous at $0$ with respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous with respect to the topologies $\tau_X, \tau_Y$, you can't say anything about $f(A)$ for $A\in\tau_X$ or $f^{-1}(B)$ for $B\in\tau_Y$, regardless of whether $f$ is injective, surjective, bijective, or none of those.  The third line of your proof, "Since $f$ is surjective, ..."  is not so, it follows from nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the example and the clarification. Seeing it explicitly has resolved much of my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is surjective, then for every $y\in Y$, there exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. It is **not true** in general that for every $B\in \tau_Y$, there exists $A\in \tau_X$ such that $f(A) = B$.

Therefore, surjective mappings *need not be* continuous.

Comment: And even if the latter were true, it would still not guarantee that $f^{-1}(B)=A$, only that $A\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$, which is not enough for continuity, either.

Comment: Indeed! For that, we would also need injectivity of $f$. @Vercassivelaunos